# Regular expression to return string from preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I would like to return the string "This is table one" from the text below:

```
$string = '[section title="<italic>This is table one</italic>"]'
```

using

```
preg_match_all("@\[section title\=\<italic\>\"(\S+ )\<\/italic\>\"\]@s", $string, $match);
```

However, i can only return those with a single word. How to have a rule that includes spacing digits or special characters?

Thanks

Comment: does the italic tag present in your input string?

Comment: Hi Avinash, have edited the question.

Comment: Have edited the syntax. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: we could get the result if your pattern is modified. See http://regex101.com/r/fU3fH9/6

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex to get the string `This is table one`,

```
(?<==\"<italic>)[^"]*(?=<\/italic>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fU3fH9/2)

OR

```
\[section title="<italic>\K[^"]*(?=<\/italic>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fU3fH9/4)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$string = '[section title="<italic>This is table one</italic>"]';
$regex =  '~\[section title="<italic>\K[^"]*(?=<\/italic>)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "This is table one"
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `\[section title="<italic>` Matches the string `[section title="<italic>`
- `\K` discards the previously matched characters, so above matched characters are discarded.
- `[^"]*(?=<\/italic>)` Matches any character not of `"` double quotes zero or more times upto the string `</italic>`

Answer (score 0):

RegEx you need is

```
(?<=italic>)[\w\s\W]+(?=<\/italic>)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tO7wK3/2)